# Trigger overflow on child when parent overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a bunch of `display: inline-block;` divs inside of a `display: flex;` parent div. When the window becomes too small, the parent div overflows the row and a horizontal scroll bar appears. One of the `inline-block` divs contains some long content, so in this case I would like this block to collapse to `overflow: ellipsis`. However, this block never technically overflows since it is the parent overflowing. How can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: auto;
}

.overflowMe {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Content</div>
    <div class="inner">Content</div>
    <div class="inner overflowMe">Content</div>
    <div class="inner">Content</div>
</div>
```

In this example, I would like the div with class `overflowMe` to collapse and overflow before the `outer` div overflows.

Pure css answers preferred but js is also acceptable.

Comment: Added code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the *.outer* container flex, let the *.inner* `overflow-x: hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  background: gold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.overflowMe {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: skyblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Content</div>
  <div class="inner">Content</div>
  <div class="inner overflowMe">Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content Long Content</div>
  <div class="inner">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **updated:** added a new answer description and removed unecessary code lines.